# How do you save an asparagus bed from comfrey?

Tags: plant-recommendations, asparagus, comfrey

I accidentally buried a lot of fresh picked comfrey stems under wood chips when building an asparagus bed. How do I save the asparagus bed from the comfrey?

Answer (score 2):

Oh dear! Comfrey is very hard to get rid off. The best hybrid to use is named 54 and is sterile to avoid wild spread.

The best way to get rid of it is to clear your crops is to use a herbicide.  Glysophate application is the best and ‘least dangerous’ as it doesn’t stay in the soil.

Please be aware of what you can use in your area. Herbicides should be used responsibly as they are harmful to the environment.

Comment: that's the problem, it's right on the edge of the watershed, so pesticides won't work

Comment: Then manual removal will have to be done regularly trying to remove as much of the plant as possible out of the ground. Plus side, make comfrey tea for your plants. I can give you a recipe but it will warrant a new question